# Trouble getting links from website scraper with BS4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the first time I'm making a website scraper and I'm relatively new to programming in general. So I'm trying to get the HREF links for all the subpages on [this site](https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/#/search?loc=Europe&lat=54.5259614&lng=15.2551187&range=50&assocs=800&fvw=c&ctry=undefined%5C):. But when I ran the code, instead of getting all the different HREF links, I keep getting the same one (the first one) 30 times. I'm sure I'm making a silly mistake here, but can't quite figure out what it is.

So here's my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

def get_html(url):
    driver = Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source

dict_href_links = {}

def get_link():
    url = '`[`https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/#/search?loc=Europe&lat=54.5259614&lng=15.2551187&range=50&assocs=800&fvw=c&ctry=undefined\`](https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/#/search?loc=Europe&lat=54.5259614&lng=15.2551187&range=50&assocs=800&fvw=c&ctry=undefined%5C)`'`
    starting_link = '`[`https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/`](https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/)`'`
    html = get_html(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    company = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-6')
    list_links = []
    # print(company)
    
    for sub_page in company:
        sub_page = soup.find('a', {'style' : 'text-decoration: none; font-size: 22px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1em; color: #000; color: #0000FF'})
    
        if str(sub_page["href"].startswith("#")):
            full_link = starting_link + sub_page["href"]
            print(full_link)

get_link()
```

And here's the output:

> Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe') `[`https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/#/search/service-providers/63?loc=Europe&lat=54.5259614&lng=15.2551187&range=50&assocs=800&fvw=c&ctry=undefined`](https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/#/search/service-providers/63?loc=Europe&lat=54.5259614&lng=15.2551187&range=50&assocs=800&fvw=c&ctry=undefined%5C)
> Process finished with exit code 0``` `` ``` ``

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: I get that link repeated 30 times. I can't put it in the post because it looks like spam.(obviously)

Answer (score 0):

This website appears to be rendered using Angular and so I don't believe BeautifulSoup will be able to scrape it. As you're already using [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) to get the webpage, I'll use it to also scrape the page, which selenium is very good at.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://iamovers.mobilityex.com/#/search?loc=Europe&lat=54.5259614&lng=15.2551187&range=50&assocs=800&fvw=c&ctry=undefined%5C")

#TODO: Add a wait in with Selenium's expected conditions to account for the cookie popup

left_component = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'left')
for company_box in left_component.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[ng-repeat="sp in sr track by $index"'):
    url_div = company_box.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-md-6')
    url_a = url_div.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
    url = url_a.get_attribute('href')
    print(URL)
```

I am using [webdriver manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) here for simplicity. You'll need to make improvements to this as for now all it will do is print out all of the company links.

You should read up more about Selenium in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Thank you! So I guess that I should do it with Selenium alone, since it makes it a lot easier. I also added  the wait in Selenium. The thing is that the list of links I get are still of the same company instead of all the different companies. If you have any insight in this, I'd really appreciate it. Anyways, thanks for your time!

Comment: That will be an error in your code as, from my testing, the code I provided prints the links of each company as expected. If my answer was helpful, you should mark it as such.